# Decryption of image is of low quality from encrypted image even i save complete 8 bits of grey scale

Tags: image, image-processing, encryption, steganography

i am doing image steganography
i have 2 images of same size,
i save 2nd image as a grey scale in first image.
i save complete 8 bits of grey scale image
but at the time of extraction the image i get is of very low quality..
here is my code

Encryption

```
for (int i = 0; i < simple.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < simple.Width; j++)
            {
                pixelToHide      =    secretGreyScale.GetPixel(j, i);
                BitsToHide       =    getBytes(pixelToHide.R);

                pixelForHiding   =    simple.GetPixel(j, i);
                AlphaBits        =    getBytes(pixelForHiding.A);
                RedBits          =    getBytes(pixelForHiding.R);
                GreenBits        =    getBytes(pixelForHiding.G);
                BlueBits         =    getBytes(pixelForHiding.B);

                AlphaBits[6]     =    BitsToHide[0];
                AlphaBits[7]     =    BitsToHide[1];
                RedBits[6]       =    BitsToHide[2];
                RedBits[7]       =    BitsToHide[3];
                GreenBits[6]     =    BitsToHide[4];
                GreenBits[7]     =    BitsToHide[5];
                BlueBits[6]      =    BitsToHide[6];
                BlueBits[7]      =    BitsToHide[7];

                newAlpha        =     getInt(AlphaBits);
                newRed          =     getInt(RedBits);
                newGreen        =     getInt(GreenBits);
                newBlue         =     getInt(BlueBits);

                simple.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(newAlpha, newRed, newGreen, newBlue));
            }
        }
```

Decryption

```
for (int i = 0; i < EncryptedImage.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < EncryptedImage.Width; j++)
            {
                pixelToDecrypt = EncryptedImage.GetPixel(j, i);

                AlphaBits = getBytes(pixelToDecrypt.A);
                RedBits = getBytes(pixelToDecrypt.R);
                GreenBits = getBytes(pixelToDecrypt.G);
                BlueBits = getBytes(pixelToDecrypt.B);

                BitsToDecrypt[0] = AlphaBits[6];
                BitsToDecrypt[1] = AlphaBits[7];
                BitsToDecrypt[2] = RedBits[6];
                BitsToDecrypt[3] = RedBits[7];
                BitsToDecrypt[4] = GreenBits[6];
                BitsToDecrypt[5] = GreenBits[7];
                BitsToDecrypt[6] = BlueBits[6];
                BitsToDecrypt[7] = BlueBits[7];

                newGrey = getInt(BitsToDecrypt);


                hiddenImage.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(newGrey, newGrey, newGrey));
            }
        }
```

getBytes is the function which convert int into bits and getint do the opposite.
PixelToHide and PixelForHiding is a Color type
Simple is the image in which i have to hide SecretFreyScale image.

Comment: Without the whole code to test results, this segment looks fine. To make sure, `pixelToHide` is already greyscale, so it doesn't matter which color plane you pick for the pixel. Suspicion: what format do you save the encrypted image? Some formats doesn't support transparency (png should be fine).

Comment: theres another problem in it as well. when i get pixel from the image picturebox it will change many bits thats y quality will decrease. but whn i use the same bitmap (encrypited one) it will give correct modified pixel value.. it mean there is a problem in setPixel() function??? i really dnt knw

Comment: and i am using *.bmp exytension for saving the image. but it dosent matter because if i dnt save image and took the image directly from picturebox thn i ll give me the same problem

Comment: I don't understand the second problem you just mentioned. Can you please update your question to elaborate a little bit and provide the complete source code?

Comment: when i read value from the Bitmap the pixels that i have modified are same and values are same as those i have changed but if i put that image to picturebox or save it and then if i read that image from picturebox than the values of the pixels are changed or u can say that the  quality of image is decreased.

Comment: Problem solved thankyou. The problem is that i was initilizing new instense of Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to see what goes on in your code as you don't show the sub functions so I'll attempt to answer with a generic approach -

Just for orders sake: For encryption you need to scale down the image you want to hide (pseudo code assuming LSB/little-endian CPU architecture):

```
((secretByte AND 00000011) << 6) OR (publicByte AND 00111111)
```

(`<<` = bit shift left)

This leaves you with an image of 2 bits or 4 colors in the lower end while the visible image will reside in the upper 6 bits.

This *will* generate a low quality (2-bits) image by the very nature of the technique. More bits than two may make the "hidden" image visible. There is a compromise that needs to be made.

Now, when you want to decrypt it you need to do it the other way, get rid of the bits for the public image (not really necessary as they will be shifted out here, but to make it more clear what goes on I'll include it) and then scale back up the 2 bits:

```
(imageByte AND 11000000) >> 6
```

If you don't scale the value the max value will be max 4 (of 255) which of course will turn out very faint.

If you don't want to do bit-shifting you can always divide and multiply instead but you'll need the bit-masks:

```
Enc: ((secretByte / 64) AND 11000000) OR (publicByte AND 00111111)

Dec: (imageByte AND 11000000) * 64
```

Comment: the other function are simply converting the bytes to int and vice versa.

Comment: but m storing all 8 bits of grey scale image.... shouldnt it give me the same image?? secondly is there other information except R,G,B in the pixel that should be kept save in order to extract image properly

Comment: @assassino Steganography works (usually) by hiding two images in two bit ranges. But for the secret image to be invisible they can only occupy the 1-2 lower bits. You can use RGB as well - the important part is to separate the bit ranges. The secret image will be reduced in quality to be able to fit into the two bits. You can encode an image or message as a for example 2D barcode and hide that or use a large image and spread a smaller image into regions which you later merge back to 8 bits.